# How to stop execution of next handler if there is an error in previous handler gin

Tags: go

I have chain of router handlers defined

```
apis.POST(/hello, authHandler("username") , myfuncHandler)
```

WHow can I force stop calling myfuncHandler if authHandler has some error. I was trying to use c.Next() to move to next handler if there is no error. But I noticed that even if there is error it moves to next handler execution.

I am using gin as server.

Comment: It would be nice to provide the code of myfuncHandler at least.

Answer (score 4):

Use `context.Abort()` with `return`

return will only stop the execution of code for that handler only. So if you are using multiple handlers then code for all other handlers will get executed.

So use context.Abort() with return

```
func authHandler(username string) {
    err := auth(username)
    if err != nil {
        context.Abort()
        return
    }
}
```